# What is the cost of a Statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

If I only ever use one `Statement` at a time would it be worthwhile cacheing it along with my `Connection`. I already cache the connection so I could cache the statement at almost no cost at all.

Essentially I suppose I am asking if there is any cost/overhead to creating a statement. I fully understand the benefits of creating prepared statements. I am talking specifically about `Connection.createStatement()` here.

Comment: I would always assume there is an overhead, but I would always assume the overhead is not worth adding complexity to your application, unless you have a measure which indicates it is a needed performance improvement.

Comment: It would be like: If my application is creating millions of statements then Yes else No...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some research into an open-source jdbc driver ([jtds](http://jtds.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jtds/branches/jTDS%201.2%20%28stable%29/src/main/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsStatement.java?revision=1120&view=markup)) suggests the following object overhead for each Statement created. I am trying to count the cost of creating a new `Statement` every time I want to query the database rather than holding one single cached one and reusing it:

1. A `Connection` - Presumably cached so insignificant.
2. A `TdsCore` - Looks like a protocol implementation but it is cached so insignificant.
3. A `ResultSet`.
4. An `ArrayList` of batched items.
5. An `ArrayList` of open `ResultSet`s.
6. Column meta data.

So it looks like the highest proportion of the cost of `Statement`s involves what is left around by any query that has been run.

Answer (score 4):

The cost of a Statement cannot be quantified independently of other factors; e.g. the database, the JDBC drivers, the SQL in the statement and so on.

You can be sure that there will be an overhead in creating a Statement (or PreparedStatement) and in executing it for the first time.  However, there's a good chance that it won't be significant to the overall application's performance.  And if it isn't, then implementing the caching code will simply be wasted effort.

You shouldn't be guessing whether this is (or isn't) going to be a worthwhile optimization.  What you *should be doing* is get your program working, THEN profiling it, THEN using the profiling data to determine what needs to be optimized.  If a significant amount of time is spent executing the same queries, then *maybe* caching will help, and maybe not.  Try it out and see if it makes a measurable difference to performance.

Comment: It is well known that caching `Connection`s is a good idea. I will therefore always cache `Connection`s without wasting time gathering metrics. I just hoped that there was some similar wisdom about `Statement`s.

Comment: Caching connections is only a good idea if it is necessary.  If it is not necessary, you've just wasted developer time by implementing it.  It so happens that there are standard connection pool libraries, and you don't waste *much* time if you use them unnecessarily.  But my point is that you shouldn't waste time optimizing ... or looking for optimization techniques ... if there isn't some evidence that it is necessary.  And for statement caching you don't have any general evidence, and I doubt that it exists.